# Rails asset paths missing fingerprint in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

We've just deployed a Rails 4.0.3 app to production and have found that asset paths generated by `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_link_tag` are missing their fingerprints. So instead of requesting something like `application-c841bd1c82c25bb1de8452d2338479f7.js`, the page is just request `application.js`.

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` is successful and generates fingerprinted files.

The bits from `config/environments/production.rb` that seem relevant are:

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

This is running on our own Apache server, not Heroku. I've looked around quite a bit and found similar problems, but none of the troubleshooting steps for those are helping here. Thanks.

**More Information**

In case it is helpful, here are the full contents (commented lines removed) of our config files:

`application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Ctrc
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.ceal.application_title = "CTRC Budgeting"

    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.pmacs_redmine.project_identifier = 'itmat-gcrc'

    config.app_data_path = '/data/web/apps/itmat/ctrc'
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      path: "/data/web/apps/itmat/ctrc/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
    }

    if ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
      config.assets.prefix = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] + '/assets'
    end
  end
end
```

`production.rb`

```
Ctrc::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.eager_load = true

end
```

I know that the application is running in production mode because if I set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

in that file, the CSS and JavaScript are compiled and requested correctly.

I'm including those assets in the page  like so:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

but it is still generating links to those assets like this:

```
<link href="/apps/itmat/ctrc/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/apps/itmat/ctrc/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

instead of the fingerprinted links I would expect to see.

Comment: is `config.serve_static_assets = false`?

Comment: It is. Sorry about that - I didn't include that config setting the first time.

Comment: do you have this `config.assets.enabled = true` in `config/application.rb` ?

Comment: are you sure you're actually running the server in production mode?

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true`

Comment: @RubyRacer That is not the problem. And `false` is recommended.

Comment: When you precompiled the assets, do the fingerprinted versions appear in `public` folder? If not, there's an issue with compiling the assets; if so, there's a problem with calling the `precompiled` assets, which is the likely issue.

Comment: I do see the fingerprinted assets in `public/assets`, so it does look like a problem getting the path to the precompiled assets.

Comment: @iceman I'm sure I'm running in production mode. If I change my production config file to set `config.assets.compile = true`, the page renders correctly. This isn't the right solution, but it is evidence that the assets themselves are OK and that Rails is using the config file and environment I'm expecting.

Comment: I've found out I can resolve this by compiling assets twice. First with the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT specified and a second time without it. If I skip either of those or reverse the order I end up with 404 for some or all assets.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I was (idiotically) deploying a different branch than I had checked out. So the changes I was making to my environment config file on my feature branch weren't taking effect -- because they weren't on the server! The fix was, obviously, to just deploy my feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be a problem with the gem [AssetSync](https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync/issues/255). Either setting `config.assets.compile = true` or removing the gem resolved the issue. Compiling assets on the fly and having your Rails serve your assets might be acceptable if you're using a CDN, but generally, taking another approach is usually recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For rails 4.x be sure to set the following:

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Comment: I've double-checked all of these and they're set correctly.